# Exception HRESULT: 0x800455BC in speech recognition in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a new app where I am using the speech recognition capability for windows phone 8. However, I am getting the following exception:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800455BC
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at ExcerciseMod7Voice.MainPage.d__4.MoveNext()

And this is the code I'm trying to use:

```
 private async void btnSpeak_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
         var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizerUI();
         recognizer.Settings.ShowConfirmation = true;
         recognizer.Settings.ReadoutEnabled = false;

         try
         {
             var result = await recognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
             if (result.ResultStatus == SpeechRecognitionUIStatus.Succeeded)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(result.RecognitionResult.Text);
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
 }
```

When I run the app and I click in the button to speak it displays a message confirmation for a few seconds and then disappears.

NOTE: I'm testing directly to my cellphone this app. (Nokia Lumia 920)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message means that the language isn't supported. I'm not sure what your language settings are but you can get the recognizer with your locale using this (swap `en-GB` with the culture you want)

```
var localRec = InstalledSpeechRecognizers.All
                       .Where(r => r.Language == "en-GB").FirstOrDefault();
```

Then set your recognizer with that language

```
if(localRec != null)
  recognizer.Recognizer.SetRecognizer(localRec);
else
  MessageBox.Show("Recognizer with the language not found");
```

If you don't explicitly set the locale above then the system will use the language set in the phone's `Speech` settings.