# Error 0X800455BC when creating a SpeechRecognizer object on Windows Phone 8.0?

Tags: windows-phone-8, speech-recognition

My Lumia 820 is running Windows Phone 8.0.  My Lumia 520 is running Windows Phone 8.1 developer preview.  Speech reco works fine on the Lumia 520, but with the 820 I get a **System.Exception** with an *HRESULT* code of **0x800455BC**.  I did some research and that error is supposed to be localization related.  It happens when the language your phone is set to is not supported by the speech recognizer:

[Exception HRESULT: 0x800455BC in speech recongnition in Windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510010/exception-hresult-0x800455bc-in-speech-recongnition-in-windows-phone-8)

Except I am not getting the same call stack as what that page shows. Also, the solution offered on that page says I should set my recognizer to the desired language explicitly.  But that's a problem since I get the error when I create the recognizer.  Since I can't create it, I can't set the language.  Other people get the error when they try to do a speech recognition session.

Note, I definitely have enabled speech recognition via the phone settings, even allowing it when the phone is locked.  Have any of you seen this and know what to do about it?  I get the error right when I try to construct the SpeechRecognizer object:

```
// Create the recognition engine.
this.SpeechRecognizerObj = new SpeechRecognizer();
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the Speech files for your Phone Language?

Comment: @DanielSteiner I have never needed to do that before so I don't know what files you are referring to.  Can you reply with a link to a page describing the download?  I am using English/US.

Comment: Well English US should be included in any case. Just doublecheck the speec settings at 

Settings > speech 

If I am not mistaken Speech is required for Speechrecognition.

Comment: @DanielSteiner This is strange. Despite having everything enabled, on a whim I tried the default O/S speech reco (Hold start button down until speech assistant appears).  When I did that, it said speech is not enabled until my new language pack is installed, check settings).  I clicked on the Settings button to go back to the Speech Settings page, but there was no mention of a language pack install in progress.  Any ideas?